# The meaning of "save with"

Tags: phrases

What the phrase "save with" means?

Context: "He never spoke of the softer passions, save with a gibe and sneer" from Sherlock Holmes.

Answer (score 0):

It's a less common use of the term "save", where it means "except for/with".

It comes from the fifth definition of save on [this page](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/save), "to set aside for future use", except the context in this case is setting it aside from the larger case.  It's meant to suggest that it is the only case in which it is excluded.

"I never steal, save for a grape or two at the supermarket", would mean I don't steal normally, and the only exception is to try a grape or two at a supermarket.